# How to better specify kindo fo ID in RESTful service

Tags: rest, api, design-patterns, restful-architecture

I'm looking for an opinion about defining contract for standard GET/PUT/POST/DELETE methods.

We have resource, let's say Client, so route will be /clients

However, we have two types of id for the client. One is the ID generated by our system. On top of that we want optionally allow customers use external id, generated by customer themselves.

So, if customer never going to add clients to the system, don't really interested about integration, and need only use method GET to read customer, endpoint will be:

```
/clients/{id}
```

However, if they want full integration, with ability to add clients, and use some their id, we want give them ability to use their own id.

We considered four possible solutions:

```
1. /clients/external/{externaId}
2. /clients/ext-{externalId}
3. /clients/{externalId}?use-external-id=true
4. /clients/{externalId} with additional header -"use-external-id": true
```

We are leaning to options 3 and 4 (can be supported simultaneously) but concerns about "restfulness" of such approach. Any opinions on this? What would you choose and why?

Answer (score 0):

REST says nothing about URLs.

How different are internal and external clients? If the only difference is the existence of an `externalId` property, just use the `/clients` endpoint and add the property to your client resource. Always assign and use the internal id property in your API, but allow queries to filter by the customer-provided external id also.

Comment: The clients are the same, we just want to be able to find them either by Id generated by our system, or id generated by external component. For example, the client can be:
Id: 1
Name: Maxim Alexeyev
ExternalId: MA

Comment: Then, if we choose second approach from the lest, I will be able to return same data either by url /clients/1 or /clients/ext-MA

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
/clients/client_id/1  - for automatically generated ids 
/clients/external_id/d23sa - for filtering on the external_id field
```

This could be extended to generically filter on any field of a resource and is the approach my company used in developing SlashDB.

Comment: This is similar to 1st approach in our list. What concerns me about this is it looks as if client_id is a resource, which is not. Resource is client.